# EXT JS Check any New record insert into Store or not

Tags: extjs

I have created a function to check whether the store record is changed or not, if record are dirty then when user pressed save button `setLoading` is true, is not dirty then do nothing.

```
function isDirtyStore(theStore) { 
        var isDirty = false;

        theStore.each(function(item){
            if(item.dirty == true){
                isDirty = true;
            }
        });
        if (!isDirty){
            isDirty = (theStore.removed.length > 0);
        }
        return isDirty;

};


var BtnRouteFareSave = Ext.getCmp('BtnRouteFareSave');
var grid = Ext.getCmp('MyGridPanelRouteFare');

BtnRouteFareSave.on('click', function(){

if (isDirtyStore(RouteFareStore)){  
grid.setLoading(true);  
}
})
```

But dirty is only checking for Edited record only, how about new record are inserted into the store? how to check ?

Answer (score 4):

`Ext.data.Store` object have `getModifiedRecords()` method which returns all records added or updated since the last commit.

So you do not need to implement your own function, just check if `store.getModifiedRecords()` returns non empty array.

If you want also check if any records were removed from store, you can add to check `store.getRemovedRecords( )`. This method returns any records that have been removed from the store but not yet destroyed on the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Is kinda weird but you could add a  listener to your store to listen for adding new reccords and inside that listener set that specific reccord dirty in order to be able to detect it in your validation.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an instance of the store with the original items in it, and compare it to a new instance, which has all of the items of the first one, plus the newly inserted one and compare both or use the [`add`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-add) and [`datachanged`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-datachanged) events.

If the `add` event is fired, flag a boolean that'll indicate that your store has new data and thus has dirty new) records.